# Why eman project is dropped from opendaylight oxygen release. Any specific reason for it to be droppped?

Tags: opendaylight

Can anyone please tell me why eman project was dropped from opendaylight Oxygen release. Or is there any other feature which can do the same job as done by eman.

Answer (score 1):

The eman project along with some other projects lost their contributors and are no longer actively maintained by anyone and thus were not included in the release. You could try posting to the eman-dev mailing list to see if anyone is still subscribed. You can always download the project and build it yourself. Perhaps you would like to reboot the project and maintain it - the ODL community would welcome your contributions.