# Opendaylight eman functionality link

Tags: opendaylight

I am looking into eman functionality. Can anyone please suggest me link to some tutorials or example which would help me understand this feature.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in [Why eman project is dropped from opendaylight oxygen release.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603707/why-eman-project-is-dropped-from-opendaylight-oxygen-release), the eman project is no longer actively maintained so you're most likely on your own although you could try the eman-dev list. Other than that there's the project page https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/EMAN:Main and/or whatever online docs were provided in releases prior to Oxygen.